# How to write regex query in elasticsearch which matches any char except slash?

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I have problem with query below:

```
"query": {
            "regexp": {
              "rest.request.uri": {
                "value": "/account/.*./price/.*./pdf"
              }
            }
          }
```

It should match only this case: /account/{account_id}/price/{price_id}/pdf

which means that * should replace only id, but it replaces everything between e.g.

/account/{account_id}/sometext/price/{price_id}/sometext/pdf

Does anybody know how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the `{...}` substrings are digits, try `"/account/[0-9]+/price/[0-9]+/pdf"` (or if there are letters as well, try using `[0-9a-zA-Z]` or even `[^/]+` instead of `[0-9]`).

Comment: If the `[^/]+` works for you, you may accept the answer below.

Comment: I will, but I am not able still because of the time.

Comment: Just FYI: `.` matches any character while `[^/]` matches any char but `/`.

Comment: Great, thanks one more time.

Comment: Please consider changing the title, it is more than misleading.

Comment: Done, hope it is better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern:

```
account/[^/]+/price/[^/]+/pdf
```

This pattern uses a "negated character class" that allows the regex engine to run quite efficiently.

Wiktor says ES doesn't need escaped slashes.  News to me.

Comment: This was not theft @Wiktor -- I submitted before your edit appeared on my screen.

Comment: What do you mean? Anyway, there is no need escaping `/` as ES does not use regex delimiters.

Comment: @Wiktor oh, I don't know about ES.